# Master menu item for multiple plugins?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, admin-menu, add-menu-page

I guess this question is more or less about aesthetics and organization rather than functionality, but I'm curious nonetheless...

I know I can add a custom menu item in the dashboard for my plugin using the `add_menu_page()` function, but my question is: Is it possible to add a "master" menu item with "sub-menu" items which would correlate to individual plugin options pages?

In other words, let's say my company name is "Guru Guy" and I have released 4 different plugins... Would it be possible to create a menu item that looked something like this:

> Guru Guy <-- Main menu item
>
> -- Plugin 1 <-- Plugin 1's options page link
>
> -- Plugin 2 <-- Plugin 2's options page link
>
> -- Plugin 3 <-- Plugin 3's options page link
>
> -- Plugin 4 <-- Plugin 4's options page link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus

Specific to your question `add_submenu_page`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page

Comment: I guess I'm not explaining it thoroughly enough. I understand how to create a submenu item, but my question is if it's possible to have each submenu item under a single parent menu item be related to completely different plugins... Rather than several submenu items related to the same plugin and it's options.

Comment: Yes the function parameter allows it to be anything you want, its basically just a blank page.

Comment: I see, so it seems then that the most difficult part would be checking to see if the parent menu already exists upon plugin activation, as well as checking for the installation of the other plugins which would be listed as submenu items.

Comment: yes exactly , for example using `is_plugin_active` but this is more a question on how you structure your system.