# How to check an admin submenu already exists?

Tags: admin-menu, add-submenu-page

To check if a menu exists, I use this:

```
if ( isset ( $GLOBALS['admin_page_hooks']['menu-slug'] ) ){}
```

But it doesn't work with submenus.

How can I do the same for submenus then?

Thank you.

EDIT:

I also tried:

```
global $submenu;

if (isset($submenu['mymenu-slug']) && in_array('mysubmenu-slug', wp_list_pluck($submenu['mymenu-slug'], 2))) 
    {$test=1;}
else
    {$test=0;}
```

$test remains equal to 0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if an admin (sub)menu already exists?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/how-to-check-if-an-admin-submenu-already-exists)

Comment: Thank you Ignat but I tried this already and it just doesn't work. I edited my question accordingly